# Debugging javascript slideshow

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I'm struggling with debugging this slideshow. I have understood everything except this part:

```
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  slides[i].style.display = 'none';
}
for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
  dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(' active', '');
}

slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = 'block';
dots[slideIndex - 1].className += ' active';
```

This is the last part of the javascript code. Please, can anyone explain this to me line by line. I have tried to use the debugger and I didn't understand how does it work.

Here is the whole code:

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Slideshow container -->
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="img1.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="img2.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="img3.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>

  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<!-- The dots/circles -->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* { box-sizing:border-box }

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides((slideIndex += n));
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides((slideIndex = n));
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('mySlides');
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName('dot');
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(' active', '');
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = 'block';
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += ' active';
}
```

By the way, I have found this on w3schools.com I'm struggling with the last part as I said I don't know:

1. Why they replace "active" with `""`?
2. Why they used this `+=` sign what does it do in this case?

please try to make it simple as simple as possible and thaaaaank youuuuu in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `for` loop hides all of the slides, by setting the CSS display property to "none". The second 'for' loop makes the "current" slide button look inactive.

The second to last line of code makes the previous slide (`slides[slideIndex-1]`) visible. The last line makes the button for the previous slide look active.

Comment: why when i remove "+" and i leave the "=" in the last line the first bullet disapear and the second one disapears when she got clicked can you explain this to me please and thank you in advance

Comment: @MedAmineElwere: You need to read up on JavaScript, and what the `+=` operator does.

Comment: i know what it does but here i can't imagine what it does in this case please if you know try to simplify it for me